# Red-black tree amortized cost of the rebalancing

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, search-trees, amortized-analysis, balanced-search-trees

I've read in different sources that the amortized cost of a red-black tree rebalancing is constant (at least during the tree creation using only insertions).

How can it be proven?

Comment: What do these "different" sources have to say about that? What *are* these sources, anyway?

Comment: @Raphael: The first ten blue links on google.com for "amortized" "red-black" are some examples, but about half of them say exactly how it can be proved. I'm not sure what else the poster thinks is left out of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the rules for what happens in a red/black tree insertion, you can see that the fixup rules for maintaining the red/black invariants only propagate upward if the newly-inserted node becomes the child of a red node with a red sibling.

Let's call a "fissionable" group in the red/black tree a black node with two red children. If you do an insertion into a fissionable group, the fissionable group will be recolored and rotated in a way that ends up eliminating that fissionable group, but which propagates the insertion fixup to a higher level in the tree. If you set the potential function of a red/black tree to be the number of fissionable groups in the tree, then the true cost of doing an insertion is 1 + r, where r is the number of groups destroyed, and the number of new fissionable groups created is at most one (you should check this), so the amortized cost of a fixup is O(1) because the potential drop is r.

It's a lot easier to think about this by looking at the isometry between red/black trees and 2-3-4 trees. A fissionable group in a red/black tree corresponds to a 4-node in a 2-3-4 tree, and if you understand 2-3-4 tree insertions it's pretty easy to see why the amortized cost of an insertion into a red/black tree is O(1).